# Creating a online Image storage for a Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, guid

I created a steganography application which stored the images in the database. Converting the application into a mvc4.Doing some modifications and someone was telling me that it is inefficient to store the images in the database. What are the alternatives? Store them online on some other storage? How would i access them, a unique GUID or url to be passed into the user interface or controller itself?

Comment: store the images on some kind of content delivery network, and store a URL to the image in the database.

Comment: Do you need to restrict access to the images? How many images? How many users? How large are the files? What networks? What database? Can you tolerate the image files getting out of synchronization with the database? ...

Comment: What content delivery network which you recommend?

Comment: "_someone was telling me that it is inefficient to store the images in the database_".  Are you having performance issues?  Random acts of performance tuning are a bad idea.